# Bootstrap collapsible panel on side

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

The accordion panel looks like this

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    This is some content.
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The content is displayed below the button.

How do I move the collapse panel to the right side of the button? As shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `bootstrap` then do it in proper way, using `rows` and `cols`. This way you will get responsive layout too.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Link with href
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        This is some content.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me. But I do not want the first column to be a pre-defined width. It has to be just the width of the button inside it. The second column is free to take up the whole width of the parent.

Comment: I have changed the CSS classes according to your requirement, it should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this in a div and give class `d-flex` and give `flex-grow-1` to *collapse*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex">
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse flex-grow-1" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    This is some content.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example works by itself (stand-alone). But when incorporated into my actual HTML document, it behaves just like the normal accordion. I am not sure where the issue is. Perhaps something to do with the Flatly theme that I use...